# Unity | Fix movement when attacking

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, boolean, move, animator

Good day! With grief in half, I wrote a code that works, but with crutches.
Question: What is the correct way to prevent the player from moving when attacking?

Now I take the attack bool in the animator, when I press the mouse button, I switch the bool to the true, make a delay of 1.5 seconds and return it to false. But when you press quickly, all the animations are mixed up and you get a mess.

Also one of the controversial ways to translate the player's speed to 0 when attacking. What is the correct way to prevent the player from moving during the attack animation?

[Animator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDqrq.jpg)

```
   void Update () {

    // WASD
    
    float Horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    float Vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    
    Vector3 move = Quaternion.Euler (0, playerCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y, 0) * new Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
    controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);

    if (move != Vector3.zero && !animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack"))
    {
        gameObject.transform.forward = move;
        animator.SetBool("Walk", true);
    }
    else 
    {
        animator.SetBool("Walk", false);
        
    }
    

    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) 
    {
        Attack();
    }
}
    
private void Attack() {
    
    animator.SetBool("Attack", true);
    playerSpeed = 0f;
    Debug.Log("Attack");
    Invoke("AttackEnd", 1.5f);
}

 private void AttackEnd()
{
    animator.SetBool("Attack", false);
    playerSpeed = 1f;
}
```

Comment: Ignore all movement commands when attacking?

Comment: It seems that I have already prohibited it where possible, but I'm not sure if it is correct.

Comment: @Alexey no you haven't .. you only blocked the rotation of the object but the `controller.Move(move * Time.deltaTime * playerSpeed);` doesn't have any condition ...

Comment: It was this moment that had to be plugged with a crutch of speed 0, tell me how you can do it better?

Comment: If attacking return?

Comment: In this moment and the problem, the switching of the bool attack is too fast

Comment: Another moment, I created a bool CanMove for testing at what moment a failure occurs and found that just at the moment of a quick second mouse click. It turns out that the "Invoke" works very crookedly, how you can return bool Attack to True without "Invoke.